# Hadoop - start-all.sh not executing

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 today and when I do `start-all.sh`, it throws this:

```
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nkhl.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nkhl.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nkhl.out
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn: line 333: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nkhl.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn: line 333: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

JPS only shows `4676 Jps`. I have mysql installed and that works just fine.

Can you please help?!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I fixed the issue. All I had to do was change the jdk version at `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` and in the `bashrc` file,to `java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

Thanks for looking though.

Comment: Also used `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` though rather wrote `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` (same for the `bashrc` file)